# Zip File downloaded from ReactJs/Axios is corrupted

Tags: django, reactjs, axios, zip

I'm trying to download a zip file from a Django api and have the user download it. There are two .csv files in the zip.

I am able to download a single .csv files individually, but when I try to download the zip and unzip, I get errors that the zip is corrupted. For sanity check, I am able to send the request via Postman. I am able to successfully download and unzip the file using that.

Here is my code fragment:

```
        axios
        .post('http://0.0.0.0:8000/sheets/', data,
            {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
                    'responseType': 'arraybuffer'
                }
            })
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res.data)
            const disposition = res.request.getResponseHeader('Content-Disposition')
            var fileName = "";
            var filenameRegex = /filename[^;=\n]*=((['"]).*?\2|[^;\n]*)/;
            var matches = filenameRegex.exec(disposition);
            if (matches != null && matches[1]) {
                fileName = matches[1].replace(/['"]/g, '');
            }
            let blob = new Blob([res.data], { type: 'application/zip' })

            const downloadUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
            let a = document.createElement("a"); 
            a.href = downloadUrl;
            a.download = fileName;
            document.body.appendChild(a);
            a.click();
```

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm struggling with the same issue :(

Comment: Posted the answer below!

Comment: The file shows corrupted in my case, without the headers also. Am executing the same code as above. Does anyone solved the issue? Any lead will be helpful.

Comment: the filename regex helped a ton!

Comment: Same issue in React. but I tried to directly from API in the browser, It will work without any problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem was that 'responseType': 'arraybuffer' should not be in "headers."

Comment: Then where should it be?

Comment: @Tomer `responseType` should not be an attribute within the object referenced by the `headers` attribute, but rather as a "root" attribute within the config object (a sibling to the `headers` attribute if present).

Comment: I also solved my problem ... resposneType should be placed in the axios config not in the header.

Answer (score 23):

To add to btbam91's reply: responseType has to be part of the config. In the above example:

```
 axios
    .post('http://0.0.0.0:8000/sheets/', data,
        {
            responseType: 'arraybuffer',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
            }
        })
```